# Updating a record using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to update a record using SQL, Got it working on multiple forms however getting an error on this particular form.

Even tried using the SQL box on phpmyadmin & still getting an error.

```
UPDATE `loanproducts` SET `product`= Working WHERE `productid` = 7
```

& im getting the following error : #1054 - Unknown column 'Working' in 'field list'

Anyone know why I'm getting this error as I have followed the code that I use on other working pages so can't figure out where I've gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is working a variable or column in loanproducts?  or should it be the string `'Working'`?

Comment: What is `Working`?  According to the error it's not a column on that table, but according to the query it's expected to be.

Comment: Incorrect SQL syntax try `UPDATE \`loanproducts\` SET \`product\` = 'Working' WHERE \`productid\` = 7` Strings must be wrapped in quotes

Comment: @David 'product' is the column, working is just a random string im trying store in that column for productid - 7

Comment: @Mucca019: Strings need to be enclosed in quotes: `'Working'`.  The code has no other way of knowing what you intended to be a string.

Comment: @Mucca019 Start by reading a ___Basic SQL tutorial___ [Maybe start here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)

Comment: yeah got it sorted now thanks had an un-needed comma in my php which caused confusion

Comment: @RiggsFolly no need to read basic tutorial as I already mentioned Ive got it working on multiple pages.

Comment: @Mucca019: Introductory tutorials will help you understand the concepts more clearly.  You may have coincidentally "got it working" elsewhere, but without understanding *why* something "works" or "doesn't work" you're not going to get very far.  The syntax of strings is going to be pretty important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant:

```
UPDATE `loanproducts` SET `product`= 'Working' WHERE `productid` = 7
```

vs your

```
UPDATE `loanproducts` SET `product`= Working WHERE `productid` = 7
```

Notice the color coding here has working in a different color (in 1st example) representing it's a string instead of a constant, variable or table column like `product` :P

All we did was add  ticks (apostrophe, single quote pick your flavor) you know this thing `'` around 'Working' so the engine knows it's a string!

Comment: I think you mean single quotes? I call ticks the one used to indicate fieldnames `

Comment: I see it so many ways, back ticks are used to denote columns, ticks, single quotes, apostrophe are all the same thing in my book.  I prefer apostrophe but I get overruled.  So I'll let the "Standards Police" figure that one out :P

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, refer to these characters as ascii 39 and 96 respectively.  Since this is a computer programming forum, anyone worthy of being here will understand those terms.